# Simplified Level 2 Prototype Processor

Tags: sentinel-2, lai

I am new to this and I really need the knowledge as it is the focus of my Master's thesis.

I will like to know what exactly the Simplified Level 2 Prototype Processor (SL2P) is, it's relationship to the Sentinel 2 and the Sentinel 2 mission.

Is it a component of the satellite, or is it a ground based validation software?

Comment: It's an algorithm to produce vegetation indices and is described in Weiss and Baret (2016) [S2ToolBox level 2 products. Version 1.1](https://step.esa.int/docs/extra/ATBD_S2ToolBox_L2B_V1.1.pdf) See also [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1385209012662441767&hl=en&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5)